# Create friendly looking URL's with mod rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make the pages on my site more search engine friendly by turning the query strings into meaningful looking page names.

For example I have a page that is this:

```
/search.php?c=18
```

I want it to look like this:

```
/doctors/MainCategoryName-18/
```

Sometimes there is a second query string so it would need to work with just one or both. For example:

```
/search.php?c=18&s=217
```

Should look like

```
/doctors/MainCategoryName-18/SubCatrogyrName-217/
```

Here's what I've tried so far but I can't get it to work.

```
RewriteRule ^search.php?c\=(.*)* /doctors/general-$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^doctors/[^?/]*-(\d+)\ /search.php?c=$1&s=$2 [QSA
```

Thanks so much for your help,

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^doctors\/[\w\-]+\-(\d+)\/?$ search.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^doctors\/[\w\-]+\-(\d+)\/[\w\-]+\-(\d+)\/?$ search.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey thanks That worked great. But what if someone types in /search.php?s=523, can I make it automatically redirect them to:/doctors/Cardiology-112/

Comment: It works really well. But what if the category name has 2 parts like this: /doctors/arthritis-specialists-111/   Some could even have 3 or 4 words as part of the category name. For SEO reasons I'd like to have the name separated by a dash.

Comment: I've edited the regexp to also include the dashes, so you can put as many words as you want. and the answer to your first comment - yes you can, but you shouldn't - friendly url does not suppose to work in that direction... and it also can't "guess" the category's name in the htaccess - if you want it to happen - you need to write it inside your search.php

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file residing in your `DocumentRoot`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#To prevent Looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#To redirect the converted URL to actual URL
RewriteRule ^doctors/MainCategoryName-(\d+)/$ serach.php?c=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^doctors/MainCategoryName-(\d+)/SubCatrogyrName-(\d+)/$ serach.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]

#To convert your URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^serach.php /doctors/MainCategoryName-%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=(\d+)&s=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^serach.php /doctors/MainCategoryName-%1/SubCatrogyrName-%2/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: using `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` is very dangerous, because even if the URL is a redirection, **you still may want to apply rewrite rules**. If I were you I would avoid such thing. Maybe, to avoid loop, before a "potential looping rule", test if the status is not 200: `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200`

Comment: @OlivierPons Ya I agree! But, I use it with care. Like you said, only when rules are not required to be applied again.